# Google Cloud API Environment Credentials on Node.js on Phusion Passenger server

Tags: node.js, environment-variables, passenger, google-authentication

I have the translation client library set up on my Windows home Node.js server and use `set GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=[PATH]` to instantiate the credentials when I start the machine. This works fine.

On the publicly hosted server I don't think the request gets as far as asking for credentials because a different error is thrown than the one saying `The request is missing a valid API key`. This would appear I forgot to set the credentials or defined the path incorrectly.

I've tried many variations of `export GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS="[PATH]"` but the error I keep getting is:

```
UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Unexpected error determining execution environment: Unsuccessful response status code. Request failed with status code 404
at GoogleAuth.<anonymous> (/usr/home/.../public_nodejs/node_modules/google-auth-library/build/src/auth/googleauth.js:163:23)
at Generator.throw (<anonymous>)
at rejected (/usr/home/.../public_nodejs/node_modules/google-auth-library/build/src/auth/googleauth.js:20:65)
 at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
```

I think this is to do with setting the environment variable in Phusion Passenger, but it's odd to me that the error I get is different.